# Is $x^p+p-1$ always irreducible in Q[x] for p prime?

Tags: ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Is $x^p+p-1$ always irreducible in Q[x] for p prime?
I have a feeling it is true, however im only able to prove it for p=2,3.How could i generalize it for every p?
Thanks

Comment: Hint: consider $(x+1)^p + p - 1$

Comment: @Crixpack so i have to use Newton's thm i.e. write $(x+1)^p$ as a sum? can you give me more details?

Comment: You don't have to write it out explicitly so much as realize that in the expansion all of the coefficients of the x terms (other than $x^p$) are divisible by p.

So you get $(x^p + ... + 1) + p - 1$ where all of the terms "..." are divisible by p, from this, using the common tests for irreducibility you should be able to finish. If you still can't then let me know and I will give you the last bit.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $P(x)$ is irreducible if and only if $P(x+1)$ is irreducible.

Comment: How do i show that P(x+1) is irreducible? I somehow think i should use eiseinstein, but im not sure now @N.S.

Comment: @J.M. Did you calculate $P(X+1)$ ? ;)